# Laravel: Uploading of file to storage not working

Tags: php, laravel, axios

I'm trying to upload image to storage. I'm currently got this object but seems unfortunate to save on app/storage

```
Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile Object
(
    [test:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 
    [originalName:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => lamborghini_veneno_art_minimalism_99945_1366x768.jpg
    [mimeType:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => image/jpeg
    [size:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 117303
    [error:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 0
    [hashName:protected] => 
    [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => C:\xampp\tmp\php82F7.tmp
    [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => php82F7.tmp
)
```

Here is my code.

In profile.vue I have click event from input file.

```
onFilePicked(event){
    const files = event.target.files
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('avatar', files[0]);
    this.$store.dispatch('uploadImage_profile',data)
        .then(response=>{

        })
        .catch(error=>{

        })
}
```

Then send using axios

```
    axios({
        url: '/prod/api/uploadImage_profile',
        method: 'post',
        data: obj
    })
    .then(response=>{
        if(response.status == 200){
            resolve(response.data)
        }
    })
    .catch(error=>{
        if(error.response){
            reject(error.response.data);
        }
    })
```

And my Controller.php

```
public function uploadImage_profile(Request $request){
    $response = [];
    //var_dump($request->file('avatar'));
    //$path = $request->file('avatar')->store('avatars');
  if($request->hasFile('avatar')){
    $file = $request->file('avatar');
    Storage::put('file.jpg', $file);
  }

  return response()->json($response);
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any error ?

Comment: @MayankPandeyz No theres no error

Comment: I found it, my default storage is FTP I just specify the location` $path = $request->file('avatar')->store('avatars', 'local');`

Answer (score 2):

You need to set  `Content-Type` as  `multipart/form-data` in your axios post request:

```
axios({
    url: '/prod/api/uploadImage_profile',
    method: 'post',
    data: obj,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
$file = $request->file('avatar');

$destinationPath = storage_path() . '/folder';  // directory under which you want to store the file

if( $file ->move( $destinationPath, $file ) )
{
    // image moved successfuly
}
else
{
    // fail to move image
}
```